# While loop and set

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have the following while loop in bash:

```
set -euo pipefail
x=0
rounds=10

while [ $x -le $rounds ]
do
    y=$(($x+1))
    echo $x
    echo $y
    ((x++))
done
```

But it stops after one iteration:

```
$ bash test.sh
0
1
```

Only when I remove `set -euo pipefail`, my loops run through completely. Why is that?

Comment: `((x++))` fails (returns non-zero).  `set -e` tells bash to exit if any command fails.  Don't use `set -e`

Comment: is there a better way of running `((x++))`?

Comment: You could use `((++x))`.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: @Saraha : What's the point in using `set -e` , when some of your commands are doing integer arithmetic? I don't see at which place in your program `-e` would make sense. Same for _pipefail_. In your case, only `set -u` makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((x++))` fails.  `set -e` tells bash to exit if any command fails.  Don't use `set -e`.

From the `bash` man page:

```
   ((expression))
          The expression is evaluated according to the rules described below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If the value of the expression is non-zero, the
          return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1.  This is exactly equivalent to let "expression".
```

You should probably just do either `echo $((x++))` to increment `x`, or do `((x++)) || true`, or `: $((x++))`, or (most reasonable) stop using `set -e`.

You *could* use `((++x))`, but I think that's a bad idea, since it hides the problem instead of fixing it.  If you ever had a loop that was running from x < 0, you would suddenly encounter a very unexpected bug.  Really, the right thing to do is to stop using `set -e`.

Comment: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-12/msg00093.html

Comment: Or `((++x))` would work.